# what is the proper way to exchange data between ctypes and c dll?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Ctypes is great for python to call c dll. To get computation result from c, normally I pass a json file path from python to c and save the result in this json-file inside c program. But I think it is trivial to repeatedly pass file path in python side and open file, write data, close file in c side and open file, read data, close file in python side again. I want to exchange json-string between python and c directly. But I don't how to manage the data pointer(char *). Is it should be passed from python to c or generated by c and deleted by c either? Any good practice to exchange data between python and c conveniently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of passing a string as input.  Just pass a byte string.  The function must not write to the string.

```
// int func(const char* s)
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.CDLL('some_dll')
func = dll.func
func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
func.restype = ctypes.c_int
result = func(b'some json data')
```

As output, create a writable string buffer:

```
// int func(char* s, size_t len)
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.CDLL('some_dll')
func = dll.func
func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_size_t]
func.restype = ctypes.c_int
output = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1000)
result = func(output,len(output))
print(output)
```

Comment: Great, this is what I want.